# Improving jdashboard jquery plugin functionality

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to add some functionality to [jdashboard plugin](http://veselov.sumy.ua/engine/go.php?url=aHR0cDovL3Zlc2Vsb3Yuc3VteS51YS91cGxvYWRzL2ZpbGVzL2RlbW8vMDMzL2pkYXNoYm9hcmQucmFy) as adding widgets to regions (columns).

It would be nice to display a link in the bottom of each column with some text: Add a widget. Clicking on it will open an ui.dialog with listed widgets from the folder called widgets where they can be stored in .html files with simple markup for example:

```
  <div class="jdash-item">
    <h1 class="jdash-head">Widget title</h1>
    <div class="jdash-body">
     Some widget text
    </div>
  </div>
```

I set a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXdFH/1/) for that. How is it possible to make this feature?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with this plugin for about a month now. I am also running into a problem when trying to add a new widget dynamically through AJAX. I can get the widget to show, but not to drag/drop/save.

But to answer one part of your question:

You need to add link to bottom of column:

```
 $(".jdash-column").append("<a href='#'>Add a Widget</a>");
```

Also, check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TXdFH/2/)

If you make any headway with adding widgets that function properly, please let me know..

Comment: Me too, need help with this